# could not run a java project from another

Tags: java, netbeans-7

I have two projects-try.java and another.java. I would like to run another,java from try.java

here is my code for another.java

```
package another;

public class Another {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Another Java Project");
    }
}
```

Here is mycode for try.java

```
package pkgtry;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Try 
{
    private static void printLines(String name, InputStream ins) throws Exception {
    String line = null;
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins));
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        System.out.println(name + " " + line);
    }
}

private static void runProcess(String command) throws Exception 
{
    Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    printLines(command + " stdout:", pro.getInputStream());
    printLines(command + " stderr:", pro.getErrorStream());
    pro.waitFor();
    System.out.println(command + " exitValue() " + pro.exitValue());
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    try 
    {
        runProcess("javac C:\\Users\\owner\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\try\\src\\pkgtry\\Another.java");
  runProcess("java C:\\Users\\owner\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\try\\src\\pkgtry\\Another");
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

After running the Try.java Its not printing anything. Its just printing build successful in netbeans. But a class Another.cass has been created

Can anyone help me?

Comment: you need to add the directory with Another.java to your class path or prepend fully qualified path to Another.java.

Comment: @HarshalPandya: The compiler doesn't look for *source* files specified on the command line in the classpath.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Of course, thats very true. Classpath was a stupid suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `Another.java` isn't in the directory you're running your code from. In particular, you *are* managing to invoke both `javac` and `java`, and it looks like both are receiving the arguments you've specified - but it can't find `Another.java`.

*Additionally*, you need to provide the fully-qualified class name to `java`, which in this case is `another.Another` as it's in the `another` package. That also means you need to compile it in such a way that will leave the class file in an appropriate directory structure.

So you want something like:

```
runProcess("javac -d . path/to/Another.java");
runProcess("java another.Another");
```

(Where `path/to/Another.java` is either an absolute filename or one relative to the working directory.)

The `-d .` will tell `javac` to build a directory structure rooted in the current working directory for the output files.

EDIT: Now we know where you're running, you could use:

```
runProcess("javac -d . src/pkgtry/Another.java");
runProcess("java another.Another");
```

Note that you *should* keep your source organized in a folder structure to match the package structure, so it should be in a directory called `another`, not `pkgtry`

Comment: no yaar. its not working. i am getting the same result after running it

Comment: @gela: Then you haven't specified the path to `Another.java` properly. Unfortunately you haven't told us *anything* about how you're running the code, which makes it hard to help you. You might want to dump the current directory to the console to see where you're running: `System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath())`

Comment: when i run System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath())  in Try .java its giving C:\Users\owner\Documents\NetBeansProjects\try\.

Comment: i hav editted the question can u go through it and help me.. is that the way to specify the path for Another.java?

Comment: @gela: That's a way to *compile* it - but it's not the way to *run* it. I'll edit my answer

Comment: thanks yaar i could run the program by using runProcess("javac -d . path/to/Another.java");
runProcess("java another.Another"); Thank you very much... :)

Answer (score 0):

The java compiler is trying to find Another.java file inside package `pkgtry`. If you put both the files in one package then you will able to achieve desired result.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   try 
   {
     runProcess("javac Another.java");
     runProcess("java Another");
   }
   catch (Exception e) 
   {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Comment: No, it's trying to find `Another.java` wherever the process is being run - which we don't know.

Comment: You should add a separate block of code to find the Another.java file and then provide the complete path here.

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      runProcess("javac C:/Users/owner/Documents/NetBeansProjects/another/src/another/Another.java");
      runProcess("java C:/Users/owner/Documents/NetBeansProjects/another/src/another/Another");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

Comment: javac  "C:/Users/owner/Documents/NetBeansProjects/another/src/another/Another.java". You can compile this way, but i am not sure about running it using "java"

Comment: i guess compiling part is ok after giving javac "C:/Users/owner/Documents/NetBeansProjects/another/src/another/Another.java". bt nothin gis been printed

Answer (score 0):

What about doing like this:

```
try 
    {
    runProcess("cd C:\\Users\\owner\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\try\\src\\pkgtry);
    runProcess("javac Another.java");
    runProcess("java Another");
    }
```

Is there any chance it could work that way?

Comment: i am getting an error in  the line runProcess("cd C:\\Users\\owner\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\try\\src\\pkgtry);